# In Rx.js, how can I distinguish which stream triggers the combineLatest method?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I'm writing my own version of [`who to follow?`](http://jsfiddle.net/staltz/8jFJH/48/). Clicking `refreshButton` will fetching suggestions list and refresh `<Suggestion-List />`, and `closeButton` will resue the data from suggestions list and refresh `<Suggestion-List-Item />`.

I want to let the closeClick$ and suggestions$ combine together to driving subscribers.
Demo code here:

```
var refreshClick$ = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(document.querySelector('.refresh'), 'click')

var closeClick$ = Rx.Observable.merge(
  Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector('.close1'), 'click').mapTo(1),
  Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector('.close2'), 'click').mapTo(2),
  Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector('.close3'), 'click').mapTo(3)
)

var suggestions$ = refreshClick$
  .debounceTime(250)
  .map(() => `https://api.github.com/users?since=${Math.floor(Math.random()*500)}`)
  .startWith('https://api.github.com/users')
  .switchMap(requestUrl => Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.getJSON(requestUrl)))

Rx.Observable.combineLatest(closeClick$, suggestions$, (closeTarget, suggestions) => {
  if (/* the latest stream is closeClick$ */) {
    return [{
      target: clickTarget,
      suggestion: suggestions[Math.floor(Math.random() * suggestions.length)]
    }]
  }
  if (/* the latest stream is suggestions$ */) {
    return [1, 2, 3].map(clickTarget => ({
      target: clickTarget,
      suggestion: suggestions[Math.floor(Math.random() * suggestions.length)]
    }))
  }
})

Rx.Observable.merge(renderDataCollectionFromSuggestions$, renderDataCollectionFromCloseClick$)
  .subscribe(renderDataCollection => {
    renderDataCollection.forEach(renderData => {
      var suggestionEl = document.querySelector('.suggestion' + renderData.target)
      if (renderData.suggestion === null) {
        suggestionEl.style.visibility = 'hidden'
      } else {
        suggestionEl.style.visibility = 'visible'
        var usernameEl = suggestionEl.querySelector('.username')
        usernameEl.href = renderData.suggestion.html_url
        usernameEl.textContent = renderData.suggestion.login
        var imgEl = suggestionEl.querySelector('img')
        imgEl.src = "";
        imgEl.src = renderData.suggestion.avatar_url
      }
    })
  })
```

You can find it in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zheeeng/vf3mu57x/).

You should note the comments in condition judgment, closeClick$ emits `[{ target: x, suggestion: randomSuggestionX }]`, suggestions$ emits `[{ target: 1, suggestion: randomSuggestion1 }, { target: 2, suggestion: randomSuggestion2 }, { target: 3, suggestion: randomSuggestion3 }]`. Subsriber render interface according to the emitted data.

May there are some ways/hacks to distinguish the latest stream in `combineLatest` or elegant modifications?

Comment: I made a work version, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zheeeng/8Lv14gb5/), I have to reuse the hot refreshClick$. I ask this question for short and elegant solution. If I can distinguish the latest stream, maybe the beeeeeest way!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to use the [`scan()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan) operator and always keep the previous state in an array:

```
Observable.combineLatest(obs1$, obs2$, obs3$)
  .scan((acc, results) => {
    if (acc.length === 2) {
      acc.shift();
    }
    acc.push(results);
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .do(states => {
    // states[0] - previous state
    // states[1] - current state
    // here you can compare the two states to see what has triggered the change
  })
```

Instead of `do()` you can use whatever operator you want of course.

Or maybe instead of the `scan()` operator you could use just `bufferCount(2, 1)` that should emit the same two arrays... (I didn't test it)